# Transform zoom conflicts with cross effect

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I'm new to this site and try to figure out how this great editor works.
When i use a transform effect on a video to get rid of the bars and zoom in, 
this transform zoom dissapears as soon as i use a cross effect to another video.
How do i prevent this to happen after using any effect?